# Using SQL query how to check a certain value of a column along with the whole values in other columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with sample data

```
Inventory 
shop_code  product_id  date      QTY
10         20          20210101  5

**EDIT: Please add additional data above too**
```

I want to select shop_codes and product_ids for which the QTY was not 0 for all the dates in the last 60 days.

**EDIT: The OP put this in an answer, It should be here**

what I am trying to is:

```
select top 1000 
       SHOPCODE, 
       ProductId, 
       COUNT(DateKey) as dayNumber 
   from   
      Inventory 
   where  
          DateKey > (the date of 60 days ago) 
      and QTY > 0 
   group by 
      SHOPCODE, 
      ProductID 
   having 
      COUNT(DateKey) = ( select COUNT(distinct DateKey) 
                         from Inv where DateKey > (the date of 60 days ago)
                       )
```

I'm not sure that it is a suitable way and wonder if there is a way rather than counting the dates

Comment: Hi malih. Can you work us on examples of what you have been trying to solve this on your own?
The community usually expects to see what you tried before asking the question, so they can see you are not just blindly asking for other people to do work for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70769562/5804455

Comment: I have edited/cleand-up the post a bit.  Please edit the post and show some additional sample data AND what you expect results to be.  Also, dates should be date data-type columns, not YYYYMMDD stored.  not as easy to query data by date functionality without converting which is not as efficiient.

Answer (score 0):

First, we calculate the date of the previous 60 days and put it in the variable numerically.
Then we extract all the products, provided that their date is for 60 days and their number is above 0, and we group them according to the store and the product ID.

Use this snippet:

```
declare @dateInt int 
set @dateInt=cast(Convert(CHAR(8),DATEADD(day,-60,  getdate())+1,112) as int)


select product_id
      ,shop_code
      ,sum(QTY) as sumQTY 
   from yourTable 
   where date>=@dateInt and QTY>0  
   group by product_id,shop_code
```

Comment: You can do this very easy without making a variable first

Comment: Yes, the same statement above can be inserted into the condition. @GuidoG

Comment: and you can even do it without converting to an int

Comment: maybe something like this `where [date] >= dateadd(day, -60, getdate())`

Comment: From what I understand in his question, `date` is a date or datetime column, so your comparision with an int variable is not valid.

Comment: This condition will not work for you because the dateadd() value is datetime and cannot be compared to a int field. error: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: you got that wrong, you are comparing a date with an int variable, that will not work. In my comparision I compare a date/datetime column with a datetime value, which will work

Comment: How did you know that date is datetime?

Comment: because the OP writes it in his question

Comment: `For example the record (10, 20, 20210101, 5) ` this looks like a date to me

Comment: when in doubt, just put both possibilities in your answer

Comment: So it is not clear in the question. This is how you perceived it. It was also easy for me to consider the type of datetime. thanks anyway :)

Comment: `For example the record (10, 20, 20210101, 5) means that on the date 2021/01/01 there was` how can it not be clear that it is a date. But ok, when in doubt then provide both possible solutions, it's that simple

Comment: Thanks @SaeedEmamYari   , But actually what I need is product_id, shopcodes for which the QTY is not 0 for neither of the dates in the last 60 days. I mean even if in one date the QTY=0 , the corresponding record wont be included in the result.

Comment: but you said QTY was not 0 for **all** the dates

Comment: @malih This is important information, please edit your question and put this information in the question. You can edit your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70765712/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but from what I understand of it and from the comments on Sayeed's answer, I think this may be what you are after

```
select top 1000 
       i.SHOPCODE, 
       i.ProductId
from   Inventory i
where  not exists ( select 1 
                    from   inventory i2
                    where  i2.shopcode = i.shopcode
                    and    i2.productid = i.productid
                    and    i2.DateKey > datepart(day, -60, getdate())
                    and    i2.QTY = 0
                  )
```